# No back button when pushed to UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having trouble understanding why there is no Back button being displayed in my iOS application.

I have a `WorkOrder` storyboard that I'm doing a "Show (eg. Push") segue to from another storyboard. The entirety of `WorkOrder.storyboard` is seen below:

[image]

I want to have a "Back" button be present in the master panel so I can unwind back to the previous storyboard. How do I go about this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: may be there is back button displayed but you cant see it. Set the nav bar tint color to black or red, to see the back button.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri That's not the case, I haven't changed the colours of anything. The back button isn't there.